# Tried everything to update ubuntu to 23.10 using sudo apt update but it shows me an erro message with two yellow "W"s

Tags: apt, gnome, updates, ppa, update-manager

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                 
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease               
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kisak/turtle/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Ign:2 https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Err:2 https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu lunar InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: some ip lol]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: some ip lol]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this is the error i get (not showing my ip) but you can see, i tried everything from youtube to reddit to github, everything doesnt work, i tried fixing this problem for **DAYS and HOURS** but it doesnt seem to work, before trying to fix the problem it showed me some red "E"s

thanks for any help/support

Comment: Incredible indeed how you did all these efforts. Did you follow a specific procedure for the upgrade or did you use your own judgement?

Comment: The usual recommendations for an upgrade are to first disable all the PPAs you added, update, upgrade, full-upgrade, then try the 23.10 upgrade. Then add back PPAs, update,upgrade,etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you installed some packages from unofficial archives (ppa, see: https://itsfoss.com/ppa-guide/). Read that page and try to understand what is not working. After you are sure of what you are doing, try to disable the ppa that blocks you. I strongly suggest you to save (backup) all your user data before doing anything else (for example, with Dejadup). If in trouble, reinstall afresh and restore from backup.